# How to access both methods of different classes at the same time?

Tags: java, oop, methods, extends

In an interview I was asked the below question.

Let say there is class A with a method `drawShape()` and there is another class B with a method `drawSquare()`.

Now there is a third class C that extends both A and B.

Now finally in my class C I want both these methods.

How do I get both these methods at same time?

Comment: You should really start reading about how Java works.

Comment: *"now there is a third class named C which is extending both the classes A and B"*  Not possible in Java.  Java does not support multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not you extends because Java does not suppert , instead you can use interface:

```
interface IA{
   void drawshape();
}

inerface IB{
   void drawsquare();
}

class A implements IA{
    ...
}

class B implements IB{
    ...
}

class C implements IA,IB{
   private A a;
   private B b;

   void drawshape(){
     a.drawshape()
   } 

   void drawsquare(){
     b. drawsquare()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Now there is a third class C that extends both A and B`

In Java, you can't extend to multiple classes.

If you want you can extend B to A, then extend C to B, in this way you should be able to access both methods

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support multiple Class inheritance: a Class can only extend one other Class.

Instead, you can use Composition (having classes inside your class) to achieve what was asked:

```
Class C {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();

    ...
}
```

Now `C` can access either method by doing `a.drawShape()` or `b.drawSquare()`.